# As a student, should I get a credit card from India to the US, or apply for a credit card in the US?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, india, travel, f1-student-visa

I am planning to travel to the US as a student. I'm currently employed at an IB in India and I could get a credit card with a very good credit limit. However, if I get a credit card after going to the US, I won't be having any income, and thus won't be eligible for a good credit limit.

So, my question is, should I get a credit card from India, like a traveling credit card(assuming it will have least FX rate) to the US, instead of getting a credit card in the US with lesser credit limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the short run, its better you get a credit card from India. Generally most cards issued in India can be used internationally. Use this for initial few months in the US till you get a credit card in US.